# Jmeter: Nullpointer Exception in Second iteration

Tags: jmeter

I have Jmeter script, in which using Parallel controller with 2 threads. In one thread, I am sending web socket traffic and another one http traffic. In first iteration everything works fine, but in second http traffic thread gives below error.

Getting same error in both Jmeter 5.3 and 5.4. Getting error in highlighted part in screenshot.

```
021-11-21 23:10:47,046 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.TransactionController.notifyListeners(TransactionController.java:285) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.TransactionController.nextWithoutTransactionSampler(TransactionController.java:223) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.TransactionController.next(TransactionController.java:135) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:221) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:174) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:221) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:174) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:291) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.controller.JMeterThreadParallel.run(JMeterThreadParallel.java:61) [jmeter-parallel-0.11.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
2021-11-21 23:10:47,047 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread@75ae80c2 - Parallel Controller(Web Socket  Http) - Http Traffic
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely seems a bug in Jmeter. Just found that, encountering error only when using Transaction Controller(that to in only second iteration). Error disappeared when I remove transaction controllers and had samplers directly.